# Repeated subject multivariate regression in SAS: PROC GENMOD

Tags: sas, statistics, bioinformatics

I have patient eye data. Each eye is assigned EyeID and each patient is assigned PatientID. Each patient has 2 eyes. I am doing multivariate logistic regression with PROC GENMOD. To adjust for the fact that there are 2 eyes per patient, I used the option repeated subject=PatientID(EyeID). Is this correct?

I have pasted my code below.

```
proc genmod data=test descend;
      class PatientID EyeID Explan1 Explan2 Explan3 / param=ref;
      model Therapy = Explan1 Explan2 Explan3/ dist=bin;
      repeated subject=PatientID(EyeID) / corr=unstr corrw;
   run;
```

Comment: Seems ok - `repeated subject=PatientID(EyeID)` indicates that single subject in your data is uniqely indicated by a combination of EyeID (e.g. left,right) and PatientID. If each eye had a separate id e.g. for 2 patients you had 4 eye ids then `repeated subject=EyeID` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reputation is not high enough to comment but the following might be helpful to you since it deals both with repeated measures and the same research subject matter.

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/188-29.pdf